# IOS: MFMailComposeViewController in Storyboard doesn't show "To:" field

Tags: ios, email

I'd like to know how to implement MFMailComposeViewController correctly using storyboards. When I implement it like a non-storyboard project (where it works fine), the Title Bar stays over the address field "To:"

### screenshot

[image]

Is there another way to do the same operation?

Comment: Could u give some detail information such as ur code for presenting the MFMailComposeViewController....

Comment: Inside view controller, I wrote this:  

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];  
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];  

It works fine in an Non-Storyboard Project.

Answer (score 0):

The `MFMailComposeViewController` needs to be presented from a view controller which occupies the full screen. It looks like you have presented it from a view controller that only occupies the area below the title (navigation) bar. Try navigating to the view controllers `presentingViewController` or `parentViewController` and having that view controller present the `MFMailComposeViewController`.